# Custom profile image as featured/thumbnail after share

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I disabled gravatar option, and putted code so user can upload custom code without having gravatar account

Full code is here:

```
   add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) 
{ 
?>
    
            <img class="user-preview-image" src="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'sidebarimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>">

            <input type="text" name="sidebarimage" id="sidebarimage" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'sidebarimage', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            




    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin' );

    function enqueue_admin()
    {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    }

    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

    function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    {
    return false;
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_POST[ 'image' ] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'sidebarimage', $_POST[ 'sidebarimage' ] );
    }
```

Question is, can I use profile image as featured (thumbnail) when I share link of user page? Now it showing "empty/default" gravatar

Comment: Please tag appropriately. `jquery` and `css` are very little involved with what you are asking here. And this is primarily a `wordpress` question, which you didn't tag with.

Comment: The social networks pick the thumbnail image from specific meta tags - so you need to see to it, that you modify those accordingly as well. But we don't know what currently creates them in your setup, could be part of the template, could be handled by a plugin like Yoast SEO or something. So you'll need to go and figure that out first of all.